# At dynamic linking, does the dynamic loader look at all object files for definitions, or only at those specified by the executable?

Tags: c, build, linker, operating-system

So I'm trying to wrap my head around static and dynamic linking. There are many resources on SO and on the web. I think I pretty much get it, but there's still one thing that seems to bother me. Also, please correct me if my overall understanding is wrong.

I think I understand static linking: 
The linker unpacks the linked libraries, and actually includes the libraries' object files inside the produced executable. The unresolved-stubs in the application object files are then replaced by actual function-calling code, which calls functions in addresses known at build time.

Dynamic linking on the other hand is what puzzles me more: I understand that in dynamic linking, the stubs in the object-code which reference yet-unresolved names, are going to stay as stubs until runtime.

Then at runtime, the dynamic loader of the OS would look through precompiled libraries stored at standard filesystem locations. It would look in the object-files of the libraries, inside their symbol tables (?) and try to find a matching function definition for each unresolved-stub. It would then load the matching object-files into memory, and replace the stubs to point to the function definitions.

So the part I'm missing is this: where does the OS dynamic loader look - does it look in the symbol tables for all object-files in the system-libraries directory? Or does it only look in object-files specified somewhere in the application-executable file? Is this the reason why at compile time we must specify all dynamic dependencies of our program? Also, is it true dynamic libraries expose a symbol-table too?

Answer (score 1):

> So the part I'm missing is this: where does the OS dynamic loader look
>   - does it look in the symbol tables for all object-files in the system-libraries directory?

No dynamic linker I'm aware of does this.

> Or does it only look in object-files
>   specified somewhere in the application-executable file?

Nor exactly this, either.

Details vary, but generally, a dynamic linker looks for specific shared libraries *by name* in various directories.  The directories searched may be built into the linker, specified by the operating system, specified in the object being linked, or a combination.  The linker does not (generally) examine libraries' symbol tables until *after* it locates them by name and selects them for linking.

> Is this the
>   reason why at compile time we must specify all dynamic dependencies of
>   our program?

Yes, though under some circumstances we *do not* need to specify all dynamic dependencies at compile time.  Some dynamic linkers support on-demand dynamic loading as directed by the program itself.  This can be used to implement plugin systems, among other purposes.

> Also, is it true dynamic libraries expose a symbol-table
>   too?

Yes.  Dynamic libraries have their own symbol tables because

1. The dynamic linker uses them to do its work, and
2. Dynamic libraries can have their own dynamic linking requirements, which are not necessarily reflected in the main program's.

Answer (score 0):

In the normal usage, "dynamic linking" is performed by the loader. "Static linking" is performed by the linker.

Generally, linkers can create either executable files or shared libraries. The linker output for both is an instruction stream that tells the loaders how to place the executable or library in memory.

> Dynamic linking on the other hand is what puzzles me more: I understand that in dynamic linking, the stubs in the object-code which reference yet-unresolved names, are going to stay as stubs until runtime

That is not [usually] correct. The linker will locate the shared library in which the symbol exists. The executable will have an instruction to find the symbol in that shared library. Linkers generally puke if they cannot find all the symbols that need to be resolved.

> So the part I'm missing is this: where does the OS dynamic loader look - does it look in the symbol tables for all object-files in the system-libraries directory?

This a system specific question. In well designed operating systems, the shared libraries are designated by the system manager. The loader uses the library specified by the system. Poorly designed systems frequently use some kind of search path to find the shared libraries (which created a massive security hole).